# Flag or revert an edit?

Tags: support, editing

Is there any mechanism in place to flag an edit for a review or revert an edit someone made? Would it be appropriate to submit an edit to reverse a change?

This question arose because I stumbled across [this](https://superuser.com/posts/100010/revisions) question on the front page. It ended up there because an edit was made to remove a tag (which would be fine) but also a word was changed. That IMO is kind of important and changes something about the question.

Submitting an edit for that edit could, depending on what it's about, lead to a kind of edit war I guess?

Comment: You have enough rep to rollback. A rollback  war is automatically flagged for moderator attention. I have rolled it back.

Comment: @DavidPostill What exactly constitutes a rollback war?

Comment: @FleetCommand When the OP or another editor rolls back the rollback :)

Comment: @FleetCommand [What triggers the "possible rollback war" flag?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/121948)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Just so you know the tag was removed, clearly indicates, not to use the tag.  The tag should be removed but Notepadd++ should be kept.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I've removed the tag.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for pointing out that I actually do have the permission. I have no idea why I did miss the "rollback" link on the review page. Still nice to have some information and opinions.

Answer (score 1):

When an edit I make gets rolled back by the owner of the post, I almost always completely ignore it, however many times my edit is rolled back by a moderator accompanied by an explanation in a comment about why edits having spelling corrections, retagging or formatting improvements should not be rolled back except for a legitimate reason.

When an edit I make gets overturned by the owner of the post with a request to ignore the post until the OP has finished editing it, I apologize for being intrusive and then ignore the post as requested. If an edit request as made by the OP in a comment, I will edit the post myself as the OP requested rather than allowing the post to be defined by only a comment which many people do not read.

I make an exception for correcting rudeness or vandalism in edits. For example someone who posted an answer may edit the original question with an edit like "All the other answers to this question are wrong, so upvote my answer.", but when I removed the disrespectful edit my edit was rolled back. In a case like this I will rollback the disrespectful edit again and again, which has the effect of getting all the rollbacks flagged for moderator attention.

In general I try to handle as much of my own editorial work as I can myself without flagging anything, in order to avoid burdening the moderators with unnecessary janitorial work.

Comment: we all try to make the site better. It was just something I was wondering about and there could've been different opinions on it as well. It wasn't meant as any kind of offense or anything. I was genuinely curious about how rollbacks work ... because I missed that I am able to issue them myself. I'm really not sure what you're getting at with your second comment, sorry.